# Inline date picker in iOS 7.1 SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker, ios7.1

I updated XCode yesterday (March 12 2014) with Version 5.1 (5B130a) and all of a sudden my Inline Date pickers stopped working properly.

[image]

However, they remain working fine on my phone.

[image]

This is how I implemented the date picker:

http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/10/31/ios-7-in-line-uidatepicker/

Any advice on what can be done?

Comment: Is this an image of the simulator?

Comment: Yes, this is how my simulator looks like now. But there was not text overlay yesterday prior the update

Comment: You need to provide information on how you have implemented the inline picker.

Comment: Sure @LeoNatan this is how I did it: http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/10/31/ios-7-in-line-uidatepicker/

Comment: Try setting the cell's "Clip subviews" to YES.

Comment: Thanks that fix it. Do you want to post this as your answer so I can grant it to you

Comment: Added an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set the `clipsToBounds` property of the cells to `YES`.